# How to iterate over each cell in a column and perform an operation on each

Tags: python, openpyxl

I have an excel document that lists several IP addresses, I need to iterate over each cell in the column and perform a ping to determine if each IP is up or not. I then need the result of the ping function written to a text file.

So in the spreadsheet in column A starting at A1 will be:

```
10.10.10.10
20.20.20.20
30.30.30.30
40.40.40.40
```

The script should read each line, ping each IP address, and then write to text file "10.10.10.10. is up, 20.20.20.20 is down", ect

```
import os
import openpyxl
import time


wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('IPS.xlsx')
sheet = wb.get_sheet_by_name('Sheet1')
with open(time.strftime("%d-%m-%Y") + "-Decom.txt", "w") as s:
    for i in range(1, sheet.max_row):
        response = os.system("ping -n 2" + sheet[i].value )
        if response == 0:
            s.write(sheet[i].value, 'is up')
        else:
            s.write(sheet[i].value, 'is down')
```

> c:\Python35\Scripts>python ping.py Traceback (most recent call last): 
>   File "ping.py", line 10, in 
>       response = os.system("ping -n 2" + sheet[i].value ) AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'value'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do `sheet[i].value`, `sheet[i]` would return a tuple of cell values in a row.

There is, though, a simpler way to iterate over the cells of a specific column:

```
for cell in sheet['A']:        
    value = cell.value

    response = os.system("ping -n 2" + value)
    s.write(value, 'is up' if response == 0 else 'is down')
```